# How to delete content of file present in multiple directories in linux

Tags: linux

Directory A having two sub directories B and C. Both B and C having same text file like "abc.txt". From directory A itself how to delete content abc.txt in both directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more general way is to use find:

```
find . -type f -name "file" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

The explanation of the command is:

```
-name "file" : file name.
-exec rm -f {} \; : delete the files that match.
-type f : specify the type of file, directory are excluded.
```

Answer (score 3):

If there could be more than two subdirectories in `A`, but you 
want to restrict you to `B` and `C`, you can use

```
rm A/{B,C}/abc.txt
```

to delete both files.

To empty their content, use

```
: > A/{B,C}/abc.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the actual files:

```
find A/ -name "abc.txt" -delete
```

Delete the "content" of the files:

```
find A/ -name "abc.txt" -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Kleene star :

```
rm A/*/abc.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

find A/ -name "abc.txt" -type f -exec rm -rf{}\;